# Xsl transformation free online editor

Tags: webapp-rec

I am looking for a [Xsl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Stylesheet_Language) transformation free online editor. I have found [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/XSL/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog_ex2) TryIt Editor, but I need some more extended one. I need a tool with custom output formatting and more.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "custom output formatting"? Indentation? Syntax highlighting? Markup rather than result?

Comment: @Eric indentation, syntax highlighting at least

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an open source in browser editor called [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/). It doesn't hace an xsl parser, but you can add one. It does have an [xml/html](http://codemirror.net/htmltest.html) and an [xquery](http://codemirror.net/contrib/xquery/index.html) parser

Comment: In other words, "roll-your-own", nothing pre-existing out there....

Answer (score 0):

Check this: http://xslt.online-toolz.com/tools/xslt-transformation.php